# uneval() adds prefix in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I successfully used [serialization helpers](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Serialization_Helpers) in Firefox userscripts.

```
function deserialize(name, def) {
  return eval(GM_getValue(name, (def || '({})')));
}

function serialize(name, val) {
  GM_setValue(name, uneval(val));
}
```

They worked for older Chrome versions too. Recently I've noticed that Chrome's `uneval()` started to add a prefix `\$1 =` to its result, breaking following `eval()` deserialization:

```
uneval([56, 67]) -> "\\$1 = [56, 67];"
```

I now have to detect and strip this extra prefix. Is there a more legitimate way to persist data in a cross-browser way? I only need this data to be restored in the same browser - no need to care about storage format.

Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey were used for tests.

Comment: JSON doesn't work? It only supports certain values (directly) but is definitely "portable".

Comment: No, it doesn't. It returns JavaScript, as it is the opposite of `eval` (which takes JavaScript and JSON-by-a-mostly-subset relation). My recommendation is to *use* JSON as in JSON.parse/stringify; and/or clarify why such is not appropriate.

Comment: Why can't [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) be used?

Comment: I was unsure if JSON is present in both Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey. Trying now. Meanwhile could you post an answer and look for duplicates?

Comment: @Basilevs: Tampermonkey uses `JSON.stringify` internally anyway: https://code.google.com/p/tampermonkey/source/browse/trunk/src/environment.js?r=91#1157